# Set a parameter in a parameter file and use it in a same workflow

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to set a parameter say a timestamp in a parameter file using a command task that triggers a Unix shell script that does this task in a workflow and later in the same workflow, use the parameter that is set earlier. Is that possible? 
 The informatica version used is 9.6

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. However, I guess you need to define the parameter file at session level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a global parameter defined at workflow level. Once the workflow starts it triggers a shell script that updates the timestamp in the parameter file used by the workflow and immediately in the next session, I use the mapping parameter in the post SQL to update a table.                                Something like this : UPDATE TABLE SET A='N' WHERE TIMESTAMP < $$TIMESTAMP .  I see that the parameter is properly updated in the parameter file, however the parameter is not replaced in as expected. Informatica replaces the parameter with a blank and hence the session fails.

Comment: What is happening is that, when the session runs, it picks the parameter value, that was set in the earlier run. i.e the old value. Say during the run 1 value was blank, the command task runs and sets a timestamp, however the session fails as there is no value set, if i re run the workflow, it again updates the timestamp, however the session picks the value that was set during the run 1. It is unable to pick the value set during the current run. What am i supposed to do to pick the value set during the current run?

Comment: If you have the parameter file at workflow level, it will be read before your command task updates the timestamp. Try to put the parameter file at session level.

Comment: Thanks a lot Samik, Was exactly the mistake that i did. I just set the parameter file at workflow level. but then when i added a worklet, it definitely read the parameter file again, as it works with out setting the parameter at the session level. I guess a property of Informatica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `Parameter file` property on a **Session**. Not just set the parameter value for a session, but make the session read the paramfile.

With Workflow parmeter file it works like this (briefly speaking):

1. Workflow is initialized and reads the assigned parameter file. All variables are set.
2. Upon session initialization all the variables and parameters are already set .

The file is not read again, variables are not re-set.

However, once a parameter file is defined as Session property, it works in a bit different way.

1. Workflow is initialized and reads the assigned parameter file. All variables are set.
2. Session is initialized, and it reads **its own** parameter file, setting all variables and parameters.

In this case, the values defined in session parameter file will be used.

Of course, it is not necessary to use Workflow level parameter file.

It is also possible to have one session that generates the parameter file for the very next session to use it. Provided it is defined as session property, as mentioned above.

Comment: Wow, Beautifully answered!! Thanks a lot for explaining this. I think, I had some basic idea about it. But very well and clearly explained!! :-) I did see that after the assignment of the parameter, if i put all the sessions under a worklet, that definitely works even with out defining a parameter file at session level. I guess when we use a worklet, informatica reads the parameter file again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :). Dont know if there is any other option. But the trick that worked for me is, if you have to set a parameter and then read back the parameter to use it in the same workflow sue to whatever requirement, then you can set the parameter and then use it in a session inside a worklet, and this perfectly works. I am not sure why but this definitely works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Assignment task for this purpose. Set a workflow variable and use it wherever you want in the same workflow.